# How to call a serverside method using jquery?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I'm trying to call a server side method, using jquery, on the textchange event of a textbox which is generated dynamically on the clientside (I dont know how to fetch the id of this). Can somebody help me to do this stuff? The script im using is as follows:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(init);

    function init() {

      $('#test').droppable(  //Div Control where i'll be dropping items
            {
              drop: handleDropEvent
            });

      $('a').each(function(idx, item) {   
        $(item).draggable({ cursor: 'move', helper: 'clone' })
      });
    }

    function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
      var draggable = ui.draggable;
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += addColumn(draggable.attr('text')) + '<br>';
    }
    $('.textChangeClass').live('change', function() { 
/* Evokes on the text change event for the entire textboxes of class .textChangeClass. Is it possible to specify the dynamic textbox generated @ clientside here? (like for e.g. :  $('#mytextbox').click(function () ) */

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Webtop.aspx/ServerSideMethod",         //This is not getting called at all.
      data: "{'param1': AssignedToID}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      success: function(msg) {
        alert("From Server");
      }
    })

    });

    });
    function addColumn(column) {

      var iHtml;

      //This is how i'm generating the textboxes along with a checkbox bound by a div.
      iHtml = '<div id="dv' + column + '" width="100px;" height="20px;" padding: "0.5em;">&nbsp;' + '<span title="ToolTipText">' + '<input type="checkbox" id="cb' + column + '" value="' + column + '" /> <label for="cb' + column + '">' + column + '</label></span><input class="textChangeClass" type="text" id="aln' + column + '">&nbsp;</div>';
      return iHtml
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: add error function to youar ajax call as i did in my answer

Comment: The solution of your problem depend not only from the code on the client side (the JavaScript code), but also from the server code. For me is absolutely unclear how you implement you server method. The most easy way would be ASMX web service or WCF, but in the case the url should be `Webtop.asmx/ServerSideMethod` or `Webtop.svc/ServerSideMethod`. Could you include in your question more information about the server code or better include the code fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you have an extra "});" although this probably isn't the problem.
2. What is "AssignedToID"?  Try adding single quotes around that.  I seem to remember having a weird problem a couple years ago related to quoting in the json.
3. Can you see the request in Fiddler/firebug/etc? Is the content correct?

You should be careful of your use of inferred semi-colons too.  If you ever minify your javascript (yeah, I know this is embedded, but I'd like to hope that one day it will be moved to a seperate js file) you're eventually going to have a problem.  Imagine some other developer comes along, does some refactoring and needs to add a return value after the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({...})return foo}
```

**EDIT**

Fiddler/Firebug Net panel are your friends...  They will allow you to inspect the request and the response from the server.  This way you don't have to add the error handler (although you may want to for other reasons eventually)

**EDIT**

To answer the other part of your question, you can access the textbox for which the change event was triggered through the use of the 'this' keyword inside of the event handler.

```
$('.textChangeClass').live('change', function(event) {
    //Note that the 'event' parameter has interesting things in it too. 
    var changedText = $(this).val();
    alert("The value in the textbox is: '" + changedText + "'");
    var data = {
        param1: changedText
    };
    $.ajax({
        ...
        //Using json2 library here to create json string
        data: JSON.stringify(data), 
        ...
    });
});
```

Note that I added the optional 'event' parameter to the event handler.  It has interesting things in it and it's something that is often overlooked by people who are new to jQuery.  Read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Comment: I removed the parameters and tried to reach the serverside method. but still didnt work. I got firebug. Dont know how to use it with scripts.

Comment: 1. Open firebug and then go to the 'Net' tab.  Follow directions to enable it.
2. Reload the page
3. Fire the change event in desired textbox
4. See ajax call to server (or lack there of)

Comment: You can also debug javascript too. Go to script table and enable it.  You can set break points in your event handler and see what's gong on.  If you're brave, you can even step into the jquery code.  Leaving the script and net debugging on slows normal browsing down a lot so you will want to make sure firebug is disabled or at the very least script and net debugging is off for normal browsing.

Comment: That's interesting and helpful. Thank you very much. But one thing i noted is my script getting breaked upon crossing the statement data: I mean, it is not even reaching success nor error call.

Comment: try using data: "{}" instead.  Did you remove the extra '});'?

Comment: yea, removed that extra braces.

Comment: @drstevens, how will the script know my serverside method's parameter type?  Maybe that's the reason why im getting an error saying "     <b> Exception Details: </b>System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method ServerSideMethod.<br>Parameter name: methodName<br><br>"

Comment: ahhhhhhh... so you are sending an http request then.  I believe it uses reflection to look at the type of the parameters.  Start with 0 parameters and an empty data field "{}", and see if you can get it working like that.  Then look at this, http://encosia.com/2009/04/07/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/

Answer (score 1):

You need to write you code of adding the event to textbox after generation of textbox otherwise it's not get fire.

1. add text box
2. After that write code to add event to text box or bind event to text box

just follow the above step will do your work

**EDIT**

Add the error function to your ajax call you will get the error ... will allow you to proceed further

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post", url: "/SomeController/SomeAction",
    success: function (data, text) {
        //...
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: how can i bind that to my dynamic textbox?

Comment: Infact the event got fired on the textchange of the textboxes but the ajax portion isnt working